# DatabaseCleaner errors in non rails app

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm trying to get DatabaseCleaner running on a non rails app where I'm using Sequel but I'm having all sorts of issues. It looks like the DB isn't being setup correctly -

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do    
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    p DatabaseCleaner.connections
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Running rspec returns -

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.8.0/lib/database_cleaner/sequel/truncation.rb:12:in `clean': undefined method `url' for :default:Symbol (NoMethodError)
  from /Users/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.8.0/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:39:in `clean_with'
  from /Users/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.8.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:62:in `block in clean_with'
  from /Users/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.8.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:62:in `each'
  from /Users/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.8.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:62:in `clean_with'
```

The line this is failing on -

```
case db_type= db.url.sub(/:.+/,'').to_sym
```

If I remove 'DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)' I get the following, notice the DB is set to :default and not :test

```
[#<DatabaseCleaner::Base:0x007fdbe41825f0 @autodetected=true, @orm=:sequel, @strategy=#<DatabaseCleaner::Sequel::Transaction:0x007fdbe416b328 @db=:default>>]

An error occurred in an after hook
NoMethodError: undefined method `resume' for nil:NilClass occurred at /Users/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.8.0/lib/database_cleaner/sequel/transaction.rb:22:in `clean'
```

Both errors indicate that the DB hasn't been set, but I can't see why. Any ideas?

Comment: i guess that your configuration is wrong. it looks as if it expects a real db-object and not a symbol. how are you defining the connection there?

Comment: I'm not explicitly defining it with DatabaseCleaner, I can't see anywhere in the docs on how to do this. I'm just setting it in my script with db = Sequel.connect(options)

Comment: did you read this section? https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner/#databasecleaner-is-trying-to-use-the-wrong-orm

Comment: Yeah that just sets the ORM explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed in database_cleaner (see https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner/commit/adb0d438dbfabaea2588f3058b1e75914706e53d), but it doesn't look like there is a new release containing the fix.  You'll have to use the git version until a new release comes out.

Comment: I had a go with this, still looks like it's not creating a sequel object for some reason. Just keeps trying to reference that :default:Symbol

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I just replaced `database_cleaner` in my Gemfile until the next version is out.

```
group :test do
  # The release version does not support sequel properly. See
  # https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner/commit/e5cb8cea.
  # FIXME: Update this, when DatabaseCleaner 0.8.1 is released!
  gem 'database_cleaner', :git => "git://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner.git", 
    :ref => "e5cb8cea"
end
```

Comment: See my above comment on Jeremy's answer. It's looks like it's not initialising the sequel object in DatabaseCleaner

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not explicitly defining [a connection] with DatabaseCleaner, I can't see anywhere in the docs on how to do this.

You can pass an existing connection to DatabaseCleaner like this:

```
connection = Sequel.connect("mysql2://user:password@host:port/database_name")
DatabaseCleaner[:sequel, { :connection => connection) }]
```